# what does "directly from the function body" mean in kotlin？

Tags: kotlin

Kotlin documents about [inline functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-functions.html#non-local-returns) says that

> Note that some inline functions may call the lambdas passed to them as parameters not directly from the function body, but from another execution context, such as a local object or a nested function. In such cases, non-local control flow is also not allowed in the lambdas. To indicate that, the lambda parameter needs to be marked with the crossinline modifier:

what does "directly from the function body" mean? how does an inline functions call the lambdas? Could you please give me some specific examples?

And the document gives an example of an inline function call the lambdas from another execution context:

```kotlin
inline fun f(crossinline body: () -> Unit) {
    val f = object: Runnable {
        override fun run() = body()
    }
    // ...
}
```

but, what is the "another execution context"? and how does the inline function call the lambdas from another execution context?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"directly from the function body" means that lambda will be only executed as a part of executing an inline function. If the lambda is stored in some property or passed somewhere else, it is considered to be executed indirectly.

Note that in the example the lambda is passed to `Runnable` object, it wasn't executed directly by the `f` function.